# jquery mobile loads actual content over injected content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile page with an empty div, i want to load content into this div like so:

seperate js script

```
$('#myPage').live('pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
    $("#content").html('<p>My html</p>');
});
```

html

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
</div>
```

Once the page loads, i can see my content for like a second, but after that jQuery Mobile just displays the empty div. How can i prevent this and keep my content? I used the pagebeforeload event because i want jQuery Mobile to enhance my mark up.

Answer (score 1):

Check-out the documentation for the `pagebeforeload` event:

> **pagebeforeload**
>
> Triggered before any load request is made...

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html*

`pagebeforeload` only fires for pages brought in via AJAX, so when this event fires, the `#content` element does not exist.

Note this excerpt from the same documentation page:

> **pageload**
>
> Triggered after the page is successfully loaded and inserted into the DOM.

This is the event you want to use, or `pageinit` which will fire for all pages, not just external ones. I believe that the `pageload` event fires before the page has actually been initialized, so any widgets you add to the HTML should be initialized automatically.

Comment: I mixed up the pagebeforeload with the pagebeforecreate event, my apologies for this. However i still have the same issue. I should also mention that i tried the pagecreate event which gives the same result.